# setting default encoding in a python.py

Tags: python, encoding, python-2.7

I am calling some sort of API which returns an object with three properties:

```
obj.name
obj.id
obj.text
```

all of these could come in different encoding.

In order to output it correctly to my terminal, I am now doing

```
print obj.name.encode('UTF-8')
print obj.id.encode('UTF-8')
print obj.text.encode('UTF-8')
```

Is there a way I can simply do one time to set my default encoding to UTF-8?

I read some other post which suggested calling the sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8'), which is not available anymore in python 2.7.x

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Normally* Python detects the output encoding from the terminal settings; you can see what Python detected by running:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.encoding
```

You really want to configure your terminal to specify the correct encoding if that doesn't work for you; set the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable on POSIX systems for example.

You can also force Python to use an encoding by setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=latin-1 python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding'
latin-1
$  PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding'
utf8
```

Comment: It throws error if I did not specifically set the encoding to UTF-8.  And my terminal has been set to in the .bash_profile:  export LANG="en_US.UTF-8".  I think my question is more about how can we set the global environment of a python script to a particular encoding rather than having to set each line individually during the print out.

Comment: @CloudYoda: That's what `PYTHONIOENCODING` does. If your bash profile already sets `LANG` then Python *should* already detect your terminal encoding, unless you are redirecting the script output with a pipe or `>` shell stream redirection.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to work...although it throw different exception in my IDE..but i think thats due to my env setting with it.

Comment: @CloudYoda: Right, if you are running Python in an IDE, then the stdout encoding detected will be different from your terminal again!